# Prove that if $g \in \mathcal{C}([0,1])$ then $A = \{ f \in \mathcal{C}([0,1]): f(x) < g(x) \forall x \in [0,1] \}$ is not open in $d_1$ metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm really struggling with this question. I tried, with no success, showing that there exists some $f \in \mathcal{C}([0,1])$ such that given $r>0$, there exists $h$ such that $d_1(f,h) < r$ and $h(x) \geq g(x)$ for some $x \in [0,1]$, which is just basically the negation of openness, but i thought that i might be able to construct such $f$. The other path I also tried to take is to construct a sequence $(f_n) \subset A^c$ such that $f_n \to f \notin A^c$, which is also the negation of closedness for $A^c$.
For either approach I found that I was unable to construct the needed object since it didn't satisfy some of the needed conditions.

Any help (or another approach that might be more feasible) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what $d_1$. I will assume that it is the one-norm metric.

Let
$$
h_n=\begin{cases}
0,&\ t<\frac12-\frac1n \\[0.3cm]
2\,\big[1-|n(t-\frac12)|\big],&\ \frac12-\frac1n\leq t\leq \frac12+\frac1n\\[0.3cm]
0,& \ t>\frac12+\frac1n
\end{cases}
$$
and put $f=g-1$, $f_n=f+h_n$. The point is that $f\in A$ and
$$
d_1(f,f_n)=d_1(f,f+h_n)=\int_0^1h_n=\frac2n,
$$
while $$f_n(1/2)=(f+h_n)(1/2)=g(1/2)-1+2=g(1/2)+1>g(1/2).$$

Comment: Right, thanks. Even though, there's no way i would've come up with that. This was a question in an andvanced calculus past exam, so I'm guessing there's got to be a simpler solution. De todas formas gracias, saludos a otro argentino!

Comment: (de nada, sigo en inglés porque si no los moderadores se enojan). It's not really difficult. All that happens is that the $h_n$ are thin and high triangles (hence, with small area) centered around $1/2$. The $f$ is obtained by pulling down $g$ by a full unit, but the $h_n$ can be made tall enough to compensate for that. I would be really surprised if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: Oh, okay, now i see. Thanks!